# address all list-items

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to address all items of a list without a forEach-loop.

For example:

```
 ColorTextBlocks = new List<TextBlock>()
        {
            tb1,
            tb2,
            tb3,
            tb4,
            tb5,
            tb6
       }
```

Is it possible to change the foreground of all items in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
ColorTextBlocks.All(c => { c.ForeGround = Color.Blue; return true; });
```

You can also do:

```
ColorTextBlocks.ForEach(c => c.ForeGround = Color.Blue);
```

But why "in one line"? A foreach loop is traditionally more readable that Linq queries...

Comment: looks great, now for some understanding: why "return true"?

Comment: Because IEnumerable<T>.All expects a Function which accepts a T and returns a bool

Comment: but forEach-loops seem to last longer... i'm working on a phone-app, should be as fast as posible.

Comment: In order to iterate other each item, `.All()` needs to return true because if you return false; the iteration will stop and you will not change the color of all your blocks.

Comment: Tiny code will not say, tiny execution time, that's just FALSE !!! If you want to execute this code as fast as possible, use the `foreach` loop, it will be much faster that all Linq queries !

Comment: @ArnaudF.: the first method is really ugly IMO. Using side-effects in LINQ queries is bad practice...

Comment: @digEmAll: that's why I've said to use the `foreach` loop. I know it's ugly but actually works. ;-)

Comment: @ArnaudF.: Sure. I just wanted to highlight it more ;)

Comment: @roqstr: actually I think that the fastest code would be `for(int i=0; i < ColorTextBlocks.Count; i++) ColorTextBlocks[i].ForeGround = Color.Blue;` but is negligibly faster than `.ForEach()` or a plain `foreach`, and anyway all 3 methods are really really fast. Are you sure this is the bottleneck of your code ?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you have the [`List<T>.ForEach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) method.

```
ColorTextBlocks.ForEach(tb => tb.Color = Color.Green);
```

But it is debatable whether this is any 'better' than a plain foreach() loop. It certainly won't be faster.

Comment: That's cheating :) It's loop :)

Comment: You're not going to be able to change a property of each element without looping over each element one way or another - be that a `foreach` loop, a `.ForEach` method, or something more contrived.  You should probably just use a `foreach` loop, it's very fast and readable - could even be one line if you like: `foreach (var tb in ColorTextBlocks) tb.Foregound = Color.Green;`.